# How to play YouTube video when clicking an HTML button?

Tags: jquery

Below is a link to an embedded Youtube video that autoplays when opening the website. I want to run it only when clicking a button using jQuery.

https://jsfiddle.net/rt5n7u2s/

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/rBWXYQZpEl8?autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: Acces in frame Dom element https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe

Comment: Try adding `?autoplay=1` to src on button click: https://jsfiddle.net/kb8h0gx9/